# Is there any sort of import for Android layout files?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

Normally in an Android layout file if you want to create a custom view you have to fully qualify the path of the class.

```
<com.blah.blah.blah.Widget>
    ....
</com.blah.blah.blah.Widget>
```

Is there anyway to import a class in the XML so you don't have to repeat package names? Some of my package names are quite long and its just a huge pain in the butt when some layouts have many custom views.

The ability to do...

```
<import path="com.blah.blah.blah.MyWidget"/>

<MyWidget>
    ...
</MyWidget>
```

Would make my life much easier.

Obviously that import tag doesn't currently exist but is there a way to extend the inflator to add it?

If not is there another way to do this?

Comment: pretty sure you can't do it via modified inflator unless you modify the Android framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to import a class in the XML so you don't have to repeat package names?

No, sorry.

> Obviously that import tag doesn't currently exist but is there a way to extend the inflator to add it?

In theory, you can set a factory on `LayoutInflater`, which gets control during the inflation process, and might be usable to accomplish this. However, that would only work for a `LayoutInflater` you use directly, not for any used by the system (e.g., `setContentView()`, default `Adapter` inflation).

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do that, unfortunately.